# Linq to SQL executing stored procedure very slow

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure which I call by

```
Int32 siteID = 1;
DateTime startDate date;
DateTime endDate date;

var result = this.datacontext.GetSummary(siteID, startDate, endDate);
```

This executes very slow with linq but in SSMS this is very quick.

When I change the SP to only accept a start date and in the SP Create the endDate by:

```
DECLARE @EndDate date
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(yy,1,@StartDate)
```

and then execute as below:

```
var result = this.datacontext.GetSummary(siteID, startDate);
```

The query is really fast again.  I am passing in the exact values as what would be the EndDate.

Has anyone seen anything like this.  The query without the end date passed in executes in 0 seconds.  With the end date it takes 6 minutes.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used the SQL server trace utility? That will give you an idea about what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I strongly recommend you take a look at sql profiler .

Comment: What are values for end date? in second case you are setting end date as just 1 month later, which might fetch few records so it works fast. But if you are setting end date as few years later of start date, then it will execute slow depending upon number of rows to search. You might also want to index your date column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at what sql is being generated, you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386961(v=vs.100).aspx) how to do that. Once you have gotten the sql see if Linq is doing anything weird when it is translating your query to SQL.

Comment: Since this is a stored proc, I'm not sure the expression tree parser is generating anything terribly unusual.

Comment: I had to cast the param date in the stored procedure then it worked!